# JQuery Mobile Beta 1 is not resizing the screen on iphone when rotated to landscape

Tags: jquery, mobile, screen-orientation

I am writing mobile app with JQUery Mobile Beta 1 and was expecting that the screen should adjust automatically on iphone when rotated from portrait to landscape and vice versa but it is not happening.

I simply checked with opening this link (Beta 1 doc demo)

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/page-template.html

but it is also not adjusting the screen.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: It seems to be same for Beta 2. I checked the demos & docs iPhone and it behaves similarly. I need to tap a screen to adjust it. Not doing automatically as in portrait orientation.

Itizme

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your document `<head>` instead of doing this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Do this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

#### Why this works

When your device oritentation changes (i.e. when you rotate it) MobileSafari will zoom into the page before it resizes the viewport. So the zoom is applied based on the portrait screen width when it should just let the page resize on its own. By setting both initial and maximum scale to 1 we disable zooming. So MobileSafari can't zoom into your page incorrectly when you rotate, thereby fixing the problem.

Also see: [jQuery Mobile bug report](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1714)

Comment: Just tested this on iOS5 and it's still an issue :-( Too bad we still need to disable scaling