# Screen Orientation Issue on Page using Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, orientation

I have just started working on mobile web apps, i am making HTML5 pages using Jquery Mobile.  I tested my pages on iPhone & iPad.  The issue is that when i change from portrait to landscape and then from landscape to portrait mode, my pages remain zoomed in. 
  How can i restore to the optimum zoom level whatever the orientation maybe, after n number of orientation changes.  I have used device-width, device-height, device-density in my meta-tag

Comment: please post your viewport meta tag in order to analyze this further...

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no">        - - - - my meta tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure from where you got yours, but this is the viewport meta tag that I am using and am pretty sure it will solve your problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"  />
```

UPDATE:

you'll need 2 different viewports, one per orientation mode.
[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon) to see how to change them on the fly.

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem with your code is that the page doesn't zoom/stretch/expand at all in the landscape mode, now i don't want that...i want it to expand in landscape mode but not stay that way when i come back to the portrait mode

Comment: so you actually need 2 different viewport tags, one for landscape and one for portrait... [here's one way to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

This post answers your question: 
[JQuery Mobile Beta 1 is not resizing the screen on iphone when rotated to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992697/jquery-mobile-beta-1-is-not-resizing-the-screen-on-iphone-when-rotated-to-landsc)
Although I do not use Beta but version 1.1.0, the solution applied.

In short, your Viewport Meta should look like this.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

```
This may be helpful for you, mantain two stylesheets in landscape and portrait mode 

 window.onorientationchange=detectIPadOrientation;

function detectIPadOrientation()
{
    //check for the mode and apply the appropriate style sheet,window.onorientationchange is the method will be called whenever the orientation changes

}
```

Comment: this seems good....but instead of having two stylesheets, can i somehow access the page scale .....this is what have in mind --  in portrait mode the page scale is 1.0 and in landscape mode it is 2.0